# C# show console output in a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been creating a project where I have a console application in c# and I need to convert the console output into the windows form.

The project I made is [Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) and the output is based on rows and columns and statuses are represented by letters.

Example (wors and columns are set to 5x5):

```
&&&&&
&&OO&
&&OO&
&&&&&
&&&&&
```

Is there any alternative way (laziest and quickest way) to show this output in a Windows Form? Can I use *label* or anything else to show it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you really wanting to render text?  With a windows form application you have access to drawing primitives like FillRectangle that may be more to your liking.

Comment: The output can be various - I'm looking for a general solution for how to perform this. I was wondering something like DataGridView?

Comment: You could generate a new datatable every step and update a datagridview. But I have a feeling that would look pretty ugly

Comment: @Wyck I am already using append:
 
`for (var column = 0; column < Columns; column++)
                {
                    var cell = future[5, 5];
                    stringBuilder.Append(cell == Status.Alive ? "O" : "&");
                }
                stringBuilder.Append("\n");`

Comment: Great!  Just slap in a RichTextBox, replace its `Text` property with the contents of your StringBuilder and you'll get poor-man's quick and dirty, but functional, depiction of your string.  So the answer to your question is "yes you can use a label or anything else. (e.g. RichTextBox)"  Maybe you actually have a more specific question?

Comment: I wrote to you via chat.stackoverflow.com

Comment: The RichTextBox approach is quick and fine. If you need interaction in the future, like when creating starting patterns, try [SourceGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SourceGrid/). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it...